# Is it possible to run a cron job randomly between 3-6 minutes?

Tags: linux, cron, centos, whenever

I defined a cronjob with the `whenever` gem for Ruby. This created a cron job for the user that runs a ruby script every 5 minutes. The user is not root and doesn't have root permissions.

I would like to be able to run this job randomly between 3-6 minutes. I'm running this job on CentOS 6.2

Comment: You could always run the cron job every three minutes and have the actual invoked code randomly delay anywhere from 0 to 3 minutes.

Comment: No, that will run every 3 minutes with a random delay.  You'd need to re-start the clock _after_ each delay.

Comment: @AdamLiss - What you suggest doing ?

Comment: You could use `at` instead of cron. The `at` job would reschedule itself at a random time 3-6 minutes in the future after it runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the script run continuously with a random delay between actions.  Put it in cron as @reboot and it will restart when the system does.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best thing you could do is setup cron to run the script every minute, and let the script decide when to actually do it's job. 
You can have the random effect by keeping track of When the script was executed for the last time